# Try various host suffixes when connecting via SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When connecting to a host via SSH, I'd like to be able to simply type `ssh hostname` to connect.

However, the setup we have currently means that I must type a fairly long suffix to connect, similar to `hostname.hosts.companyname.com`.

Is it possible to set up SSH to cycle through several hostnames before giving up a connection without adding them to my hosts file? For example. if I type in
`ssh hostname`, I would like SSH to:

1. Attempt to SSH to `hostname`, if that fails after a short timeout:
2. Attempt to SSH to
   `hostname.hosts.companyname.com`, if that fails after a short timeout:
3. Attempt to SSH to
   `hostname.companyname.com`, and if that fails then it should print
   the error.

However, we have >1000 hosts and I would rather not add an alias to everything. I would prefer this to be default behaviour.

The above is a short example. I would prefer the ability to add something in the range of 30 potential domains to this list, which is why `resolv.conf` `search` is not an option (as it's limited to 6 domains).

Comment: Is your DNS zone not set up to search unqualified host names in the local zone? When I run `host foobar` inside the network of my university faculty it will find `foobar.my-faculty.my-university.de` (assuming that host name exists). Alternatively you set up host name aliases in the SSH client configuration.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It's not no. I wasn't sure if that was going to be the best way to set it up or if there was a decent way of doing it via SSH config only.

Comment: What is in your `/etc/resolv.conf` regarding search domain(s) ?  That could fix it for you...

Comment: As you connect to hosts, they (their public key) will get added to `known_hosts` locally and a base autocompletion system uses that file, meaning that if you do `ssh hostname[TAB][TAB]` will show you options, without having to define specifically each host.

Comment: @ivanivan See my comment on roaima's answer.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek That's interesting, I never knew that! That could be a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your DNS `/etc/resolv.conf` according to these two steps:

1. There may be a line `domain` or `search`. If there is, replace `domain` with `search` in the file, and continue to the next step.
2. Append `hosts.companyname.com companyname.com` to the search list. If there was no `search` (or `domain`) directive, create one with these two values.

Example result

```
nameserver 192.168.1.254
nameserver 192.168.2.254
search hosts.companyname.com companyname.com
```

This will allow unqualified names to be resolved through `/etc/hosts` and DNS according to your criteria.

Comment: I'd like to use the `search` part of resolv.conf, but it's limited to 6 domains and 256 characters. I'd like more like 30 domains and 500+ characters. As I understand it that isn't possible without recompiling. It's also a bit annoying to get resolv.conf changes to work properly with resolvconf, but that's a different problem.

Comment: @ConnorBell your question requests support for only two (or three) different suffixes. It would be well worth updating your question to explain to would-be answerers the scale of your production environment requirements. I wouldn't have suggested a change to `/etc/resolv.conf` if I'd know you wanted completion across ~30 domains.

Comment: Edited, apologies. Out of interest, do you think a `dig axfr` is a potential workaround for this? Create an alias to a function that does an `axfr` then check for the presence of the search string at the beginning each entry?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options:

**config file**

You generate an `~/.ssh/config` file with the aliases:

```
Host hostname
    HostName hostname.hosts.companyname.com
```

Assuming the correct hostnames are static. Of course, this is somehow similar to changing the `/etc/hosts` file.

**shell function**

You define a shell function for the command name `ssh` or something you have to call explicitly like `ssh-hosts`.

```
ssh () {
        hostname="$1"
        test -z "$hostname" && return 128

        for suffix in "" .hosts.companyname.com .companyname.com ; do
                test_hostname="$hostname$suffix"
                if [ -n "$(ssh-keyscan "$test_hostname" 2>/dev/null)"; then
                        ssh "$test_hostname"
                        return $?
                fi
        done
}
```

Of course, you could use this approach for generating the `config` file, too. If you do not have a list of all the host names then you could even use the shell function for adding new `Host` blocks to the `config` file and check the file before running `ssh-keyscan`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm trying to avoid having to write down aliases for every host I need to connect to, I'd rather have it cycle through or check the existence via dig or something prior to trying to connect.

Comment: @ConnorBell See my edit.

Comment: Ooh, that shell function looks exactly like what I wanted. I'll give that a go tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: I don't care to elaborate on this, but, assuming OpenSSH, one might create one or many sections in `~/.ssh/config` which uses `ProxyCommand` to cycle through various FQDNs, based on the hostname when connecting to the remot host. That way you don't need to wrap `ssh` and you would end up with a procedure that is employed only for specific hostnames, or patterns.

Comment: This looks good, with one exception: on my platform at least, `ssh-keyscan` always returns 0 (success) regardless of whether or not it actually succeeded matching a hostname.

Comment: @roaima Sorry, I should have checked that. I have corrected my answer.